# Best practice for ASP.NET Web API design?

Tags: rest, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to create a REST'ish web service backend with an ASP.NET Web API, EF5 Code First approach. Looking now for some advice to avoid the maybe most known novice errors.

Whats the best way of modelling the controller structure for a many to many scenario like the following.

Let's say we have blog posts with tags associated to it. A blog post can have many tags, and a tag can be assigned to many blog post. Blog posts and tags each belong to customer. Pretty standard I would say. But my first concern is how to update blog posts by the following (standard?) endpoint design.

```
GET    - /api/posts/{id} => Load the post by id
DELETE - /api/posts/{id} => Delete the post by id

POST   - /api/posts/     => Create a new post from the JSON in the body
PUT    - /api/posts/{id} => Update the post from the JSON in the body. Tags as well
```

1.) Is it good practice to POST the tags simply in an array `[{"name":"tag1"}, {"name":"tag2"}]` and let the server find out if the tags are new or already existing for the customer and they just need to be assigned to the to create blog post.

Doing it in two steps (first create the post and then create/assign the tasks) doesn't feel right in the disconnected web world.

2.) More or less the same goes for the update process. Would it be good practice to just PUT the whole object and let the server try to do the update itself?

Currently I have this "basic" scenario implemented with the tool chain mentioned above. But the solution already feels fairly complicated. Especially fiddling and setting the many to many associations by hand makes things more complex than it should I think.

When it now comes to concurrency handling I'm not really convinced that all this is easy to handle in the disconnected scenario when everything comes down from the client and the server needs to find out everything.

So what is the "correct" implementation of this (easy?) scenario from API's point of view? Might it be easier to split up entity creation/update? But then I would ask myself how to tie the distinct requests so that the server could now that 2 or more request belong to 1 creation/update.

Hopefully somebody reads until this point and can follow my wooly thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find it helpful to read about POST vs PUT, since both can be used to "create" and to "update." It's up to you which ones you want to support. This answer should help:
[PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

In short, PUT is defined as idempotent, guaranteed that the result will be the same whether you PUT something 1 time or 100 times. Partial updates should not be done with PUT. It may be more useful to think of your PUT as something that will add (if the resource at that id does not exist yet) or replace (if it does). POST is "messier" in its function; it can be used in all kinds of ways.

In regard to your questions:

1) If I understand correctly, you're asking to POST a post object that includes an array of its associated tags (which may or may not be new). That's fine; you just need to have some logic on the server to figure out if it needs to add any of those tags. If you wanted to you could require it to be an array of the IDs of existing tags, but I think that would make the API harder to use than it needs to be. Behaviors like that are based on your needs and your customers' needs. I would think that in most cases one step would be better... but you can still provide the option to add tags and assign them later, too.

2) Yes, it is good practice to PUT the whole object. As far as objects that include tags that don't exist yet (which would require adding them), I am not so sure this would be "correct" unless the ids of the tags to be created were included. Even if it's not "correct," you could choose to do it anyway as long as you do not allow duplicate tags to be created (which would violate idempotence). Perhaps someone else could weigh in on this.